# Please Explain Octave-Error : operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x10)

Tags: arguments, octave

I have an issue running a certain script in octave.
This is the code that produces the error:

```
#germanium
T=410:20:600;
x=linspace(400,410,100);
y=linspace(10^9,10^9,100);
k=8.5*10 .^(-5);
Eg=0.59;
Nc300=1.02*10^13;
Nc=Nc300*((T/300).^(3/2));
n=Nc*(e.^(-Eg/(2*k*T)));
plot(T,n,x,y,'m');
grid on
xlabel('Temprature');
ylabel('Electron Density n');
title('Germanium n(T)');
```

As mentioned in the Title, the error that is produced is the following:
***error: ger5: operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x10)***
I have done a lot of testing, and I figured that the problem originates from the T variable on the 9th line : **n=Nc*(e.^(-Eg/(2*k*T)));**
The codes run fine without it. For example :

```
#germanium
T=410:20:600;
x=linspace(400,410,100);
y=linspace(10^9,10^9,100);
k=8.5*10 .^(-5);
Eg=0.59;
Nc300=1.02*10^13;
Nc=Nc300*((T/300).^(3/2));
n=Nc*(e.^(-Eg/(2*k*500)));
plot(T,n,x,y,'m');
grid on
xlabel('Temprature');
ylabel('Electron Density n');
title('Germanium n(T)');
```

In which case I simply replaced T with 500 , the code runs perfectly fine.
Sadly T, can not be replaced by a certain number since it is the variable used in my graph. Although I did some digging, I never managed to fully understand this error, or how to fix it, thus any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a . before your *, /, and ^ signs. This will ensure that octave uses scalar multiplication instead of matrix multiplication.

```
n=Nc.*(e.^(-Eg./(2.*k.*T)));
```

Comment: Oh, I swear  I tried that already... Thanks a lot for the response, my issue is solved. :)

Comment: @ForeverTinkering Please let us know what the solution was so others that have the same problem can benefit from your experience.

Comment: @Silver can you please answer this. idk what is wrong here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666436/how-to-write-costfucntion-formula-in-octave-its-from-andrew-ng-assignment